# UVM Phase Query

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have couple of questions in relation with UVM phases `build()` and `run()`. They might be applicable to other verification methodologies as well
a> Why is the `build()` phase executed in top-down order. Does this mean we need to new all the components in the `build()` phase and then proceed with execution of `build()` of other sub-components instantiated in the class?
b> During the `run()` phase is something like `super.run()` called? What is the order of execution of `run()` phase

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `build_phase()` of the UVM executed in top-down order because the children don't exist until they are constructed within the `build_phase()` of the parent component (And the UVM recommends using the factory `create()` method instead of calling the constructor `new()` directly). The `build_phase()` is also executed top-down so that the parent can provide override setting that the children will use when they execute their `build_phase()`

The run_phase() of each component is executed concurrently with no defined order you can depend on.

You only need to call super.*method*() if you are extending a class an need the functionality of the base method. There is nothing inside the run_phase() of a `uvm_component`, so there is no need to call `super.run_phase()` when extending from it. You may want to call it when extending your classes from your base classes.